# Designing custom layout in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to create the layout below using compose. I've been looking for similar designs, but I'm not sure if some things has become deprecated or something; since some things do not function. Anyone has any idea how to create something similar as in the image or why my code is not displaying as in the image?

[image: Image: https://gyazo.com/f0d618d66eb17e6d70329103344943b4]

My Code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.BasicTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.customcomposable.ui.theme.CustomComposableTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            CustomComposableTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Greeting()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Type here...") }
        BasicTextField(value = "Type here...", onValueChange = { newText ->
            text = newText
        },
        label = {
            Text(text = "Title")
        })
    }

}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    CustomComposableTheme {
        Greeting()
    }
}
```

My Code Preview:

[image: code preview screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Material Design Components `androidx.compose.material`
[See material.io](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android), here they have two links to the docs of the text field for compose [doc ref](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#TextField(kotlin.String,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.text.input.VisualTransformation,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardOptions,androidx.compose.foundation.text.KeyboardActions,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Int,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.material.TextFieldColors)), if you scroll down you see some examples as well that explain some stuff.

You need to change `BasicTextField` to a `TextField` or `OutlinedTextField` depending on the style you want.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Greeting() {
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        var textfieldA by remember { mutableStateOf("") } // Start with a empty field
        var textfieldB by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = textfieldA,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                textfieldA = newText
            },
            label = {Text(text = "Title field A")},
            placeholder = { Text("Type here...") } // placeholder / hint
        )
        OutlinedTextField(
            value = textfieldB,
            onValueChange = { newText ->
                textfieldB = newText
            },
            label = {Text(text = "Title field B")},
            placeholder = { Text("Type here...") } // placeholder / hint
        )
    }
}
```

[image: Example picture]

Comment: Thanks @Stefan de Kraker ! Will read more into what you sent and see if I manage to solve it.

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Stefan de Kraker! That solved it and now it works like a charm! Will explore it more in detail from the links as well. Cheers again man!

Comment: Happy to hear! Thank you for accepting my answer!